# How to load js file with Nuxt properly? Strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I have an HTML/CSS/JS template with a lot of js-files (jQuery and other plugins). Now, I want to make it dynamic with Nuxt.js. The first step was to copy the index.html to the Nuxt project and apply all the data between the head-tag to the nuxt.config.js as well as all the CSS-files and JS-files. The page renders and the console gives me no errors. Checking the source code tells me, that webpack bundles all js-files into app.js and the css-stuff is directly inside the source code. That's the behaviour I wanna have.

But there is a strange "bug". Everytime I load  the page a modal comes up which is not dynamic so no JS is working. I cannot get rid of it by clicking at the X. I searched for the file where that logic is and just added an "alert" to the inital line in order to make sure the file is called. It works, but: as soon as I put the alert in the "$(function(){ ...})" it does not get executed. In my raw HTML project it does.

I have no clue why it does not get executed. I installed the npm package for jQuery as well.

**That works:**

```js
;(function($){
 'use strict';
 
 alert("CHECK");
 
 $(function(){
  

  document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);

  if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
   $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
  }
    
  ...........
```

**That does not:**

```js
;(function($){
 'use strict';
 
 
 $(function(){
  
  alert("CHECK");

  document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);

  if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
   $('body').css('cursor', 'pointer');
  }

....................
```

My `nuxt.config.js` looks like this:

```js
css: [
    "@/assets/css/style.css",
    "@/assets/css/responsive.css",
    "@/assets/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"
  ],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [
    // JS Core Libs
    { src: "~/plugins/js/libs/jquery-2.2.4.min.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/js/libs/retina.min.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/js/plugins/jquery.scrollTo.min.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/js/plugins/jquery.localScroll.min.js", mode: "client" },


    // JS theme files
    { src: "~/plugins/js/plugins.js", mode: "client" },
    { src: "~/plugins/js/script.js", mode: "client" }
  ],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
   */
```

Answer (score 1):

Go the answer by myself:

I must import jQuery in the file that uses it. I supposed that a npm install is enough ...